# Read XML data saved in csv file via R

Tags: xml, r

This is the first time I work on data in XML format, and I am trying to understand the issues & semantics of this. I have a data saved in .csv file containing XML. It got more than 100,000 lines, and I want to extract this data to a dataframe.

I used `read.csv` a typical cell looks like

```
<Assessment>
  <Key>Demographics</Key>
  <Name>Patient Demographics</Name>
  <AssessmentProvider></AssessmentProvider>
  <AssessmentVersion>1.0</AssessmentVersion>
  <AssessmentDate></AssessmentDate>
  <Questions>
    <Question>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <QuestionType>Label</QuestionType>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Key>PHN</Key>
      <QuestionText>Healthcare # (Required):</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Text</QuestionType>
      <Answer>999999999</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Key>PHN_Type</Key>
      <QuestionText>Healthcare Number Issued By (Required):</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Combo</QuestionType>
      <DataItems>
        <DataItem Value="1" Code="AB">Alberta</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="2" Code="BC">British Columbia</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="3" Code="MB">Manitoba</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="4" Code="NB">New Brunswick</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="5" Code="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="6" Code="NT">Northwest Territories</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="7" Code="NS">Nova Scotia</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="8" Code="NU">Nunavut</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="9" Code="ON">Ontario</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="10" Code="PE">Prince Edward Island</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="11" Code="QC">Quebec</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="12" Code="SK">Saskatchewan</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="13" Code="YT">Yukon</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="14" Code="OT">Other</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="15" Code="US">United States</DataItem>
      </DataItems>
      <Answer>1</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>4</Id>
      <Key>FirstName</Key>
      <QuestionText>First Name (Required):</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Text</QuestionType>
      <Answer>Merkel</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>5</Id>
      <Key>LastName</Key>
      <QuestionText>Last Name (Required):</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Text</QuestionType>
      <Answer>test</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>6</Id>
      <Key>DOB</Key>
      <QuestionText>Date of Birth (Required):</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>DateTime</QuestionType>
      <Answer>2/4/1999 12:00:00 AM</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>6</Id>
      <Key>Gender</Key>
      <QuestionText>Gender:</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>YesNo</QuestionType>
      <YesButtonText>Female</YesButtonText>
      <NoButtonText>Male</NoButtonText>
      <Answer>0</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>7</Id>
      <Key>MailingAddress</Key>
      <QuestionText>Current Mailing Address:</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Text</QuestionType>
      <Answer>123 elk place</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>8</Id>
      <Key>Province</Key>
      <QuestionText>Province (Required):</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Combo</QuestionType>
      <DataItems>
        <DataItem Value="1" Code="AB">Alberta</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="2" Code="BC">British Columbia</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="3" Code="MB">Manitoba</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="4" Code="NB">New Brunswick</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="5" Code="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="6" Code="NT">Northwest Territories</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="7" Code="NS">Nova Scotia</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="8" Code="NU">Nunavut</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="9" Code="ON">Ontario</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="10" Code="PE">Prince Edward Island</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="11" Code="QC">Quebec</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="12" Code="SK">Saskatchewan</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="13" Code="YT">Yukon</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="14" Code="OT">Other</DataItem>
        <DataItem Value="15" Code="US">United States</DataItem>
      </DataItems>
      <Answer>1</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>9</Id>
      <Key>Postal</Key>
      <QuestionText>Postal Code:</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Masked</QuestionType>
      <InputMask>L#L #L#</InputMask>
      <UpperCaseAction>True</UpperCaseAction>
      <Answer>T1A2B1</Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>10</Id>
      <Key>Email</Key>
      <QuestionText>Email Address:</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Text</QuestionType>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>11</Id>
      <Key>MobilePhone</Key>
      <QuestionText>Mobile Phone:</QuestionText>
      <QuestionType>Masked</QuestionType>
      <InputMask>###-###-####</InputMask>
      <UpperCaseAction>False</UpperCaseAction>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </Question>
  </Questions>
</Assessment>
```

How do I proceed from here to make a data frame? I am new to `XML` package too. (I will probably edit this question bit later to make sure I haven't posted any sensitive ID or information online) Thank you in advance.

I have used following syntax and still trying to figure out.

```
file <- "Z:\\Project\\PIP\\PIP.xml"
xmlfile<-xmlParse(file, useInternalNode=TRUE)
xmltop<- xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root
test <- xmlSApply(xmltop[["Worksheet"]][["Table"]], function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
test_df <- data.frame(t(test),row.names=NULL)
```

I used the following syntax to extract each cell reading from `csv` and  appended the results to a dataframe. The syntax worked was:

```
file1 <- "Kiosk.csv"
csv<-read.csv(file1, header=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
zz<-file("xml.txt", open="wt", encoding="UTF-8")
sink(zz)
cat(unlist(unclass(csv[1,1])))
sink()
file <- "xml.txt"
xmlfile<-xmlParse(file)
xmltop<-xmlRoot(xmlfile)
ns1<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(xmltop,"//Assessment/Questions/Question/Answer"))
ns2<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(xmltop,"//Assessment/Questions/Question/Key"))
ns1<-cbind(ns2, ns1)
```

Comment: can you provide a dropbox or google drive link to an actual sample of a couple lines of the CSV?

Comment: Hi, here is a smal sample file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5n7yrw0hdya6t6z/sample.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: So far, `xmlParse` didn't work on column read by `read.csv`. I saved csv file as xml database, and was able to load it in R. `file <- "Z:\\Project\\PIP\\PIP.xml";
xmlfile<-xmlParse(file, useInternalNode=TRUE)`

Comment: `xmltop<- xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root;
test <- xmlSApply(xmltop[["Worksheet"]][["Table"]], function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue));
test_df <- data.frame(t(test),row.names=NULL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. You can process the column by row. The following does so and extracts `Id`, `Key` & `Answer` from the XML in each row. The result is a three item list of data frames (well, data tables) that look like:

```
 ##    Id            Key               Answer
 ## 1:  1     Disclaimer                   NA
 ## 2:  2            PHN            999999997
 ## 3:  3       PHN_Type                    1
 ## 4:  4      FirstName                  sal
 ## ...
```

You can make them all one big data frame/data table, process them individually, add fields, etc. I use data tables since one may need to use the `fill=TRUE` parameter to `rbindlist` which is a real time-saver.

```
library(XML)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

dat <- read.csv("sample.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

lapply(dat$V1, function(xml_cell) {

  question_list <-
    xmlParse(xml_cell) %>%
    xpathApply("//Question", xmlToList) %>%
    lapply(function(x) {
      x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
      x
  })

  rbindlist(lapply(question_list, "[", c("Id", "Key", "Answer")))

})
```

Comment: It gives me an error:` Error in rbindlist(lapply(question_list, "[", c("Id", "Key", "Answer"))) : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list `

Comment: `xpath= "//Assessment/Questions/Question[7]/QuestionText"`

Comment: it gives you an error off of the sample CSV you provided or the actual/full CSV? [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/33tiupl71jtz99n/sample.csv?dl=0) is how my version of excel (OS X) saved out the xlsx to CSV.

Comment: Wait. If you modified the XPath I used, then all bets are off. What elements do you need to extract?

Comment: Error comes from actual CSV. Ideally I like to extract everything that comes with <Answer> tag.

Comment: I was able to extract the data: `zz<-file("xml.txt", open="wt", encoding="UTF-8")
sink(zz)
cat(unlist(unclass(csv[1,1])))
sink()
file <- "xml.txt"
xmlfile<-xmlParse(file)
xmltop<-xmlRoot(xmlfile)
ns1<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(xmltop,"//Assessment/Questions/Question/Answer"))
ns2<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(xmltop,"//Assessment/Questions/Question/Key"))
ns1<-cbind(ns2, ns1)`